# ionic native camera taking picture but not showing it .i want to take picture and show it on the same page

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am trying ion native camera api , thats takin picture as the camera shows up and i can click an image but tha image is not shoing up

i am using android oreo , ionic 3 and latest cordova and running app on a real device

```
<-- file home.html-->`
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button round (click)="eventofClick()">Round Button</button>

  <p><img src="{{image}}" /> </p>
```

{{image}}

```
</ion-content>
<--home.ts-- ------------------------------------------------------>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  image: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public camera: Camera) {
    console.log("constructor");

  }
eventofClick() {
    console.log("called");
    console.log('inside');
    const options: CameraOptions = {
quality: 100,
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}


     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
   // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
   let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  }, (err) => {
   // Handle error
  });
}
}
```

i want after taking picture i want to show it along
what i am getting as output is  [image]

and at console i am getting `1549019043619.jpg:1 GET unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.catalyst.android.safra/cache/1549019043619.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: can u get any error or try console log the ImageData and check what u get

Comment: @kevalnayak i have updated the question along with the error on console and with the output i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, this will return you an FILE_URI of your image. If you are uploading image to the server try to show images from your server after uploading. or You can show it directly with base 64. For Base64 you have to change `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` to `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` in `CameraOptions`.
upload Image and Show it.

```
takePhoto(){
      const options: CameraOptions = {
              quality: 80,
              destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
              encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
              sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
             // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
             // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
             console.log(imageData);
               this.imageUpload(imageData) / pass your URL in upload function
            }, (err) => {
             // Handle error
            });
    }


imageUpload(path) {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      let options: FileUploadOptions = {
          fileKey: 'image',
          fileName: '.png',
          chunkedMode: false,
          //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        }
        fileTransfer.upload(path, 'Server_URL', options)
          .then((data) => {
          let res = JSON.parse(data.response);
          if (res.success == true) {
              //server will return you image name Push that name into an array and show it on your View
          }
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: it is giving me some path like  
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A4112
but that's not accessible
i want to show it just after selecting image.

Comment: Ionic doesn't support Native URI's to display Image directly.
Do you only want to Show Images or Also want to upload images to the server?

Comment: both , if u can guide me

Comment: Upload it on server and then show it inside your application.

Comment: I have updated my answer with uploading code. use this pluign https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-transfer/